# До какого предела можно упростить файловую структуру Java-проекта?

Tags: java

С точки зрения человека, не знающего Java углублённо, структура папок src/main/java, а потом ещё папка с доменом и папка с именем сайта - избыточная структура.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С точки зрения логики и рациональности, достаточно одной корневой папки для исходных файлов, одной - для скомпилированных классов и (опционально) одной папки для тестов. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `Source` может быть любая система подпапок, назначение которых очевидно (например, "Entities", "Controllers", "Models") - в отличие от таких папок, как "main" и "java", которые кэп обошёл стороной.

Что касается папок, соответствующих пакетам, то, насколько я изучил теорию, они нужны для того, чтобы избегать конфликтов имён классов. Поэтому если мы пишем библиотеку - то да, без пакетов не обойтись (но и в этом случае их можно положить в `Source` без `main` и `java`). А если мы пишем приложение (для себя или на заказ), при этом все собственные утилитарные классы типа `Utils` и `Arrays` вынесем в отдельные модули (или даже в maven-пакеты, чтобы повторно использовать их), то для тех классов, что у нас приложении, нужды в пакетах не должно быть вовсе (правда, я не знаю, как тогда импортировать классы, но это ещё не значит, что импорт не возможен).

Итак, какие подводные камни есть на пути создания в проекта структуры, показанной на втором рисунке?

Comment: будет ли удобно искать файлы мышкой и скролом, если файлов будет например 500+? Будет ли более прозрачная архитектура в таком проекте?

Comment: @Mike, Ни в коем разе. Похоже, я недостаточно объяснил, что в Source могут быть любая система папок, назначение которых очевидно из названия. Сейчас подправлю вопрос.

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать, выглядит примерно так: я уже изучил один язык программирования - JavaScript и технологии, необходимые для разработки. Теперь я изучаю другой язык программирования - Java и технологии связанные с данным языком (в данном случае maven) и мне "не нравится" как они сделаны, мне нравится как это сделано (сборка проекта) в JavaScript, почему бы в Java не сделать так же?

Comment: Если отвечать на ваш вопрос по сути - структура проект может быть любой, но нужно понимать, что делая ее столь "кастомной" вам прийдется забыть про такой удобный инструмент как maven и делать все руками, используя команду javac и прописывая все зависимости в вашем проекте. На вопрос: зачем maven создает папки src/main/java и зачем они вообще нужны, вам, по хорошему, ответит человек, который разработал maven, который сделал структуру проекта такую, какую сделал.

Comment: Не стоит думать, что за месяц, два, три или может год изучения Java вы вдруг поняли, что сборщик Java-проектов, который используется в миллионах проектов, можно было сделать лучше.

Comment: @notaProgrammer, "почему бы в Java не сделать так же?" Говоря это, возможно, Вы подразумеваете, что устоявшиеся практики в Java - единственный правильная методология. Мой основной язык, TypeScript, не обязывает придерживаться какой-либо конкретной структуры проекта, потому при создании такой я руководствуюсь логикой, рациональностью и главное - простотой в поддержке. Начав изучать Java, я увидел, что устоялась традиция создавать какие-то непонятные папки типа `java` и `main`. Если они нужны, то замечательно, но хотелось бы знать, чем они так важны.

Comment: @notaProgrammer ответ на второй комментарий: разве в maven нельзя с помощью соответствующих плагинов указать кастомные пути?

Comment: Путь к исходному файлу в вашем проекте может быть любой, но все исходные файлы должны лежать в src/main/java. Есть другой сборщик Java-проектов - Gradle. Там вы можете и это настроить. В maven - нет.